# Matrix elements' values are different when displayed each element wise

Tags: matrix

I have written a code that uses as matrix A, an image. when i display the entire matrix by simply entering A and then hitting enter i get a set of values which shows the first element as 28. But when I enter the command to display a specific element, like A(1,1) i get a different value which is 199. why is it so? What am I missing?
The code is:

```
 A = imread('E:\images\lenaa.bmp')
 W = A(1,1)
```

Comment: Can you mention the code you have written?

Comment: Please put it in the question. The formatting is messed in the comment.